# Incorrect Flash Drive size

Tags: usb-drive

My 32gb Corsair Voyager GT flash drive is only showing 100mb total space after formatting.  How do I correct this issue and get all 32gbs back?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? - please either [add it to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/473535/edit), or use http://paste.ubuntu.com/. Also, how did you format the drive?

Comment: What filesystem did you select in the format? Did you format the first partition, or the device iteslf?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you can try the "Disk Utility".  If that fails, it may be because the USB has been partitioned incorrectly.  If that is true, then you should use "GParted" to re-partition and format.  You should format your USB to Fat32 to be compatible with most other operating systems, but that is your choice to decide.

GParted is available through the Ubuntu Software Center, if not already installed and Disk Utility should have been installed with your Ubuntu Package.

You may already know this, but, you need to use caution when using GParted, or you could damage your HDD if you select the wrong drive.  Just be sure you are selecting the USB.